# reload page automatically without needing to RE-enter URL again Django

Tags: python, html, django, reload

My webpage consists of 2 parts, *upper part* is a section that let user to enter data while *bottom part* displays all the data in database in a table form. When user selects "Add" button in the upper part, the data will be saved into database and being outputted in a table in bottom part of the webpage. Is there anyway to show the table once i select the "Add" button ? Right now what the code is doing is when "Add" button is being selected, it will load a new form but then the whole table will disappear. I have to **manually** type this address again "http://127.0.0.1:8000/hrfinance/lscholarship/" then only the table will appear. Even with refreshing the page will not work. Below is my code in

**views.py:**

```
def scholarship(request, id=None):
    query_results = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
            scholarship.save()
    else:
        form = ScholarshipForm()
        id = request.GET.get('scholarship')
    query_results = Scholarship.objects.all()
    data = {
            'query_results':query_results,
            'form': form
           }
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Application(models.Model):
    studentID = models.CharField("Student ID", max_length=8, validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)], primary_key=True, default="")
    studentName = models.CharField("Student Name", max_length=500, default="")
    scholarship = models.TextField("Scholarship")
```

**add_remove_scholarship.html**

```
<div align="center" >
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return validation()" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.errors }}
    <p>Upload File: {{ form.doc }}</p>
    <p>Faculty: {{ form.faculty }} </p>
    <p>Opening date: <input id="odate" type="date" name="openDate"> </p>
    <p>Closing date: {{ form.closeDate }} </p>
    <input type="submit" name="AddScholarship" value="Add Scholarship"   >
</form>
</div>
<br></br>
    <button id="button" type="button">Delete Selected Scholarship</button>
    <br></br>
    {{query_results}}
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
    <tr align="center">
        <th> Scholarship </th>
        <th> Faculty </th>
        <th> Open Date </th>
        <th> Close Date </th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr align="center">
        <td>{{item.doc}}</td>
        <td>{{item.faculty}}</td>
        <td>{{item.openDate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.closeDate}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to use the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. This will solve your problems as well: the GET request will clear the form and show the new query results.

If the form is successfully saved, you simply return a redirect to the current page. The browser will then do a GET request. This prevents accidental duplicate form submissions when e.g. the user reloads the current page when it is still a POST request:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def scholarship(request, id=None):
    query_results = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
            scholarship.save()
            # Return a redirect to the same page
            return redirect('/path/to/current/page/')
    ...
```

Comment: '/path/to/current/page/' is : 'lscholarship' if my urls.py for this is : url(r'^lscholarship/$', views.scholarship, name='lscholarship'), ??

Comment: i tried 'lscholarship' but i will get an error saying : "NoReverseMatch at /hrfinance/lscholarship/
Reverse for 'lscholarship' not found. 'lscholarship' is not a valid view function or pattern name." please help as i am really new to django and i am learning it

Comment: With `redirect()` you can use either the url path (so `/hrfinance/lscholarship/`) or the name of the url, which will be reversed by Django. Are you using URL namespaces (i.e. by setting the `app_name` attribute in your urlconf)? Otherwise, `redirect('lscholarship')` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
def scholarship(request, id=None):
    query_results = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
            scholarship.save()

    else:
        id = request.GET.get('scholarship')
    query_results = Scholarship.objects.all()
    form = ScholarshipForm()
    data = {
            'query_results':query_results,
            'form': form
           }
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', data)
```

you need to move the query out side the `else` condition.

Although, this method would take a lot of time as the number of rows in the database increases. A better method to do this would be to use [jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method to update the data in the database and show it dynamically using javascript/Jquery once the database is updated.

Comment: do u mind to write part of the code for me to start off using jquery Ajax since i am a newbie to Django and want to learn all types of way for the same functionality to improve efficiency

Comment: did this work to solve your problem? I am afraid I can't write code for your problem. But I am sure you will find plenty of tutorial to learn Jquery when you will google it. All the best.

Comment: yes it works. thank you very much :) but the form will contain the previous one i entered. Is there any way to make all the field empty ?

Comment: I wil need to look at your models and templates for that.

Comment: i have edited my question to include models and template

Comment: I have edited my answer. I slightly misunderstood your second query."form will contain the previous one i entered. Is there any way to make all the field empty ?". All you need to do is initialize your form with an empty form after saving the data into the database. And can you please mark this my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: if you remove 'form' : form from data set, there will be no input text box

Comment: what do u mean by "initialize your form with an empty form after saving the data into the database" ? do u mean use default value ?

Comment: By initializing, I mean to create an unpopulated form (using `form = ScholarshipForm()`). So this form will not contain values entered in previous submit.

Comment: its because u have removed "form = ScholarshipForm()" this so it will get error if i include ' 'form' : form' in the data set

Comment: I have not removed it completely. I have just moved it outside the scope of `else` condition.

Comment: in this sentence, "form will contain the previous one i entered. Is there any way to make all the field empty ?", i mean after i have selected the "Add" button, the field still contain the values that i entered. In normal circumstances, once u have submitted a form, when submission is done, the field will be either default or blank. Hope this explanation makes you clear what i am trying to ask

Comment: oh sorry it's all my bad....alright i will now mark your answer as the correct answer since it is really working. thank you once again :)